# Deployment of Flask based Api (using waitress) to Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, waitress

I am trying to create a docker container for a simple Flask based Api (python 3 dependant)  but I am having issues and I don't understand what the issue is.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install waitress
CMD ["waitress-serve", "--call CoreApi:create_app"]
```

I am then building and running it as follows:

```
docker build -f GameApi/Dockerfile -t coreapi .
docker run -d -p 2020:2020 coreapi
```

The docker container dies after a few seconds and if I check it I get:

```
$ docker logs 45f8008d787a
Error: option --call coreapi:create_app not recognized

Usage:

    waitress-serve [OPTS] MODULE:OBJECT
```

Should I be calling waitress using python -m waitress --call CoreApi:create_app

Comment: Does that need to be two separate options `"--call", "CoreApi:create_app"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
CMD ["waitress-serve", "--call CoreApi:create_app"]
```

to this

```
CMD ["waitress-serve", "--call", "CoreApi:create_app"]
```

and it should work

Comment: Thank you, the stack overflow pages I looked at seemed to imply I needed to separate them, but your change fixed it.